# Practical use for Dispatcher.DisableProcessing?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

What is a common real life use for [Dispatcher.DisableProcessing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.disableprocessing.aspx) in WPF? Can I use it to suspend rendering and layout when I build a complex UI in code?

Answer (score 6):

As per MSDN:

> Disabling dispatcher processing is an
>   advanced method that is intended to
>   eliminate the chance of unrelated
>   reentrancy.

So you're doing some work on the same thread the `Dispatcher` is executing on, but you don't want it processing events whilst you do that work. I think the really pertinent point is:

> The effects of disabling processing
>   are as follows:
>
> ```
> * CLR locks will not pump messages internally.
> ```

If I understand this correctly, it means that you can safely lock and not have the dispatcher pump events as a result (which might cause undesired reentrancy).

Comment: Maybe that is just a language problem but what is a reentrancy?

Answer (score 2):

I can shared a case we've encountered recently. It's from the `PropertyChangedEventManager` used inside WPF for `PropertyChanged` event handler management. We've captured the stack when the GUI is dead:

```
0:000> !mk
Thread 0:
           SP               IP
00:U 00000000002b7ef8 0000000076efc3ea ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa
01:U 00000000002b7f00 000007fefcfc1420 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xe8
02:U 00000000002b8000 0000000076db1743 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+0xb3
03:U 00000000002b8090 0000000076c28f7d user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12a
04:U 00000000002b8130 0000000076c262b2 user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x46
05:U 00000000002b8170 000007fefeaeacd6 ole32!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0xc2 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 1222]
06:U 00000000002b81c0 000007fefec0a422 ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0x102 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\sync.cxx @ 109]
07:U 00000000002b82d0 000007feec2865f2 clr!MsgWaitHelper+0x8e
08:U 00000000002b8340 000007feec286559 clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x29b
09:U 00000000002b8440 000007feec2b8591 clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x7d
0a:U 00000000002b84c0 000007feec286eb1 clr!SynchronizationContextNative::WaitHelper+0x181
0b:M 00000000002b88a0 000007feee7c9c39 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait(IntPtr[], Boolean, Int32)(+0x29 Native)
0c:U 00000000002b88e0 000007feec19a7f3 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
0d:U 00000000002b8920 000007feec19a6de clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
0e:U 00000000002b8960 000007feec19ae76 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x251
0f:U 00000000002b8b10 000007feec300d01 clr!Thread::DoSyncContextWait+0xc2
10:U 00000000002b8c70 000007feec300c32 clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x4867e
11:U 00000000002b8d70 000007feec2b8591 clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x7d
12:U 00000000002b8df0 000007feec2b883d clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0xc0
13:U 00000000002b8e80 000007feec64046d clr!CRWLock::RWWaitForSingleObject+0x4d
14:U 00000000002b8f20 000007feec5b15b7 clr!CRWLock::StaticAcquireReaderLock+0x3b99af
15:U 00000000002b8f80 000007feec1f7ba7 clr!CRWLock::StaticAcquireReaderLockPublic+0xa7
16:M 00000000002b90f0 000007feee7f2a9c System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)(+0x6 IL,+0xfc Native)
17:M 00000000002b9250 000007fe91bf5243 Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewDataControl.set_CurrentCellInfo(Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewCellInfo)(+0x0 IL,+0x313 Native) [c:\projects\Stride\Telerik_UI_for_WPF_Source_2015_1_0401\Controls\GridView\GridView\GridView\GridViewDataControl.cs @ 1019,5]
18:M 00000000002b92c0 000007fe9219b3f7 Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCell.OnGotFocus(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)(+0x37 IL,+0xa7 Native) [c:\projects\Stride\Telerik_UI_for_WPF_Source_2015_1_0401\Controls\GridView\GridView\GridView\Cells\GridViewCell.cs @ 1176,6]
19:M 00000000002b9340 000007feedb8a36f System.Windows.UIElement.IsFocused_Changed(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)(+0x26 IL,+0xaf Native)
1a:M 00000000002b9380 000007feee7d6a0d System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)(+0x52 IL,+0xdd Native)
1b:M 00000000002b9410 000007fee366e285 System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)(+0xa IL,+0x275 Native)
1c:M 00000000002b97f0 000007feee7d668a System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)(+0x2 IL,+0xfa Native)
1d:M 00000000002b9960 000007feee7d359c System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Wind(+0x3f8 IL,+0x54c Native)
1e:M 00000000002b9c90 000007feee7d25be System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType, Boolean)(+0x2bb IL,+0x31e Native)
1f:M 00000000002b9e10 000007feee7d90c1 System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyKey, System.Object)(+0xb1 Native)
20:M 00000000002b9e90 000007feedbf3d9e System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.OnFocusedElementChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)(+0x4f IL,+0xee Native)
21:M 00000000002b9ee0 000007feee7d6a0d System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)(+0x52 IL,+0xdd Native)
22:M 00000000002b9f70 000007fee366e285 System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)(+0xa IL,+0x275 Native)
23:M 00000000002ba350 000007feee7d668a System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)(+0x2 IL,+0xfa Native)
24:M 00000000002ba4c0 000007feee7d359c System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Wind(+0x3f8 IL,+0x54c Native)
25:M 00000000002ba7f0 000007feee7d25be System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType, Boolean)(+0x2bb IL,+0x31e Native)
26:M 00000000002ba970 000007feee7d6fd1 System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object)(+0xa1 Native)
27:M 00000000002ba9e0 000007fee36d5d0f System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnGotKeyboardFocus(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs)(+0x10 IL,+0x7f Native)
28:M 00000000002baa40 000007feedb9a8a6 System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)(+0xa IL,+0x56 Native)
29:M 00000000002baaa0 000007feedb9a090 System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)(+0xf0 IL,+0x270 Native)
2a:M 00000000002bacd0 000007feedb8744e System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)(+0x61 IL,+0x14e Native)
2b:M 00000000002bad60 000007feedb838a4 System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)(+0x16 IL,+0x64 Native)
2c:M 00000000002badc0 000007feedbaedaa System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()(+0x1f1 IL,+0x42a Native)
2d:M 00000000002bae60 000007feedbb389e System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ChangeFocus(System.Windows.DependencyObject, Int32)(+0x284 IL,+0x63e Native)
2e:M 00000000002baef0 000007feedbb2624 System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.DependencyObject, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)(+0x4e IL,+0x94 Native)
2f:M 00000000002baf60 000007feedbb2491 System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.IInputElement)(+0x5f IL,+0x31 Native)
30:M 00000000002bafc0 000007feedb79bcf System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.OnSetFocus(IntPtr)(+0xaf IL,+0x10f Native)
31:M 00000000002bb0e0 000007feedb9423b System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)(+0x1e1 IL,+0x54b Native)
32:M 00000000002bb2a0 000007feedb932f1 System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)(+0x8e IL,+0x141 Native)
33:M 00000000002bb310 000007feee7cb45a MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)(+0x39 IL,+0x14a Native)
34:M 00000000002bb3c0 000007feee7cb2e0 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)(+0x5b IL,+0x80 Native)
35:M 00000000002bb410 000007feee7cb15a System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)(+0x7e IL,+0x5a Native)
36:M 00000000002bb470 000007feee7cb0e7 MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)(+0x11 IL,+0x47 Native)
37:M 00000000002bb4d0 000007feee7c846c System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)(+0xce IL,+0x2bc Native)
38:M 00000000002bb570 000007feee7ca9d0 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)(+0x129 IL,+0x140 Native)
39:M 00000000002bb670 000007feee9759d7 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int32, Int64, Int64)
3a:U 00000000002bb700 000007feec1fb42e clr!UMThunkStub+0x6e
3b:U 00000000002bb790 0000000076c29bd1 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1ad
3c:U 00000000002bb850 0000000076c272cb user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xc3
3d:U 00000000002bb8b0 0000000076c26829 user32!_fnDWORD+0x2d
3e:U 00000000002bb910 0000000076efbd75 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue
3f:U 00000000002bb998 0000000076c2685a user32!ZwUserMessageCall+0xa
40:U 00000000002bb9a0 0000000076c268a2 user32!RealDefWindowProcWorker+0xa4
41:U 00000000002bba70 0000000076c2760e user32!RealDefWindowProcW+0x5a
42:U 00000000002bbab0 0000000076c275a4 user32!DefWindowProcW+0xfc
43:U 00000000002bbb00 0000000076c29bd1 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1ad
44:U 00000000002bbbc0 0000000076c23bfc user32!CallWindowProcAorW+0xdc
45:U 00000000002bbc10 0000000076c23b78 user32!CallWindowProcW+0x18
46:M 00000000002bbc50 000007feee7cb599 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)(+0x9 IL,+0xb9 Native)
47:M 00000000002bbd40 000007feee9759d7 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int32, Int64, Int64)
48:U 00000000002bbdd0 000007feec1fb42e clr!UMThunkStub+0x6e
49:U 00000000002bbe60 0000000076c29bd1 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1ad
4a:U 00000000002bbf20 0000000076c23bfc user32!CallWindowProcAorW+0xdc
4b:U 00000000002bbf70 0000000076c23b78 user32!CallWindowProcW+0x18
4c:M 00000000002bbfb0 000007feee7caa86 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)(+0x154 IL,+0x1f6 Native)
4d:M 00000000002bc0b0 000007feee9759d7 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int32, Int64, Int64)
4e:U 00000000002bc140 000007feec1fb42e clr!UMThunkStub+0x6e
4f:U 00000000002bc1d0 0000000076c29bd1 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1ad
50:U 00000000002bc290 0000000076c272cb user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xc3
51:U 00000000002bc2f0 0000000076c26829 user32!_fnDWORD+0x2d
52:U 00000000002bc350 0000000076efbd75 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue
53:U 00000000002bc3d8 0000000076c2908a user32!NtUserPeekMessage+0xa
54:U 00000000002bc3e0 0000000076c29055 user32!PeekMessageW+0x105
55:U 00000000002bc430 000007fefebaff92 ole32!CCliModalLoop::MyPeekMessage+0x52 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 1733]
56:U 00000000002bc4a0 000007fefebb0109 ole32!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage+0x49 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 1500]
57:U 00000000002bc510 000007fefeb3e153 ole32!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x5353f
58:U 00000000002bc560 000007fefec0a422 ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0x102 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\sync.cxx @ 109]
59:U 00000000002bc670 000007feec2865f2 clr!MsgWaitHelper+0x8e
5a:U 00000000002bc6e0 000007feec286559 clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x29b
5b:U 00000000002bc7e0 000007feec2b8591 clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x7d
5c:U 00000000002bc860 000007feec286eb1 clr!SynchronizationContextNative::WaitHelper+0x181
5d:M 00000000002bcc40 000007feee7c9c39 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait(IntPtr[], Boolean, Int32)(+0x29 Native)
5e:U 00000000002bcc80 000007feec19a7f3 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
5f:U 00000000002bccc0 000007feec19a6de clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
60:U 00000000002bcd00 000007feec19ae76 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x251
61:U 00000000002bceb0 000007feec300d01 clr!Thread::DoSyncContextWait+0xc2
62:U 00000000002bd010 000007feec300c32 clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x4867e
63:U 00000000002bd110 000007feec2b8591 clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x7d
64:U 00000000002bd190 000007feec2b883d clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0xc0
65:U 00000000002bd220 000007feec64046d clr!CRWLock::RWWaitForSingleObject+0x4d
66:U 00000000002bd2c0 000007feec5b0e98 clr!CRWLock::StaticAcquireWriterLock+0x3b98e8
67:U 00000000002bd310 000007feec1f77d7 clr!CRWLock::StaticAcquireWriterLockPublic+0xa7
68:M 00000000002bd480 000007feee7dca9a System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener(System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged, System.String, System.Windows.IWeakEventListener, System.EventHandler`1<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>)(+0x4a Native)
69:M 00000000002bd500 000007feee7dc8d7 System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged, System.EventHandler`1<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>, System.String)(+0x37 Native)
6a:M 00000000002bd550 000007fee36bc902 MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.ReplaceItem(Int32, System.Object, System.Object)(+0x584 IL,+0x702 Native)
6b:M 00000000002bd690 000007fee36bbcbc MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32, System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView, System.Object, Boolean)(+0xa7 IL,+0x13c Native)
6c:M 00000000002bd710 000007fee412602d MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32, System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView)(+0x0 IL,+0x3d Native)
6d:M 00000000002bd760 000007fee36f3a2e MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourcePropertyChanged(System.Object, System.String)(+0x1b IL,+0x5e Native)
6e:M 00000000002bd7a0 000007feee7dcf19 System.Windows.WeakEventManager+ListenerList`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].DeliverEvent(System.Object, System.EventArgs, System.Type)(+0x54 IL,+0xa9 Native)
6f:M 00000000002bd850 000007feee7b7863 System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEventToList(System.Object, System.EventArgs, ListenerList)(+0xf IL,+0x33 Native)
70:M 00000000002bd8a0 000007feee7f300d System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)(+0x1de IL,+0x66d Native)
71:U 00000000002bda00 000007fe8cce0111 CLRStub[StubLinkStub]@7fe8cce0111
72:M 00000000002bdac0 000007fe8f6f38c2 *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MyCompany.Core.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for MyCompany.Core.dll
MyCompany.Core.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedNotifiableExtension.SetValue[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](MyCompany.Core.ComponentModel.IPropertyChangedNotifiableEx, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs, System.__Canon ByRef, System.__Canon, S(+0x5c IL,+0x1a2 Native)
73:M 00000000002bdb20 000007fe8f6f36f2 MyCompany.Core.ComponentModel.NotifyPropertyChangedBase.SetValue[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs, System.__Canon ByRef, System.__Canon)(+0x0 IL,+0xd2 Native)
74:U 00000000002bdb80 000007feec29f0b7 clr!InstantiatingMethodStubWorker+0xc7
75:M 00000000002bdc40 000007fe923d56f1 *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MyCompany.Modules.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for MyCompany.Modules.dll
MyCompany.Modules.Blotters.ViewModels.MyViewModel.SetOrders(MyCompany.Modules.Models.MyModel[], MyCompany.Modules.Models.MyModel[])(+0xd IL,+0x31 Native)
76:M 00000000002bdc80 000007feee7cb228 System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)(+0x3f IL,+0x128 Native)
77:M 00000000002bdce0 000007feee7cb0e7 MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)(+0x11 IL,+0x47 Native)
78:M 00000000002bdd40 000007feee7ce9f1 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()(+0x9e IL,+0x281 Native)
79:M 00000000002bde00 000007feeb0839a5 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)(+0x72 IL,+0x285 Native)
7a:M 00000000002bdf60 000007feeb083719 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)(+0x0 IL,+0x9 Native)
7b:M 00000000002bdf90 000007feeb0836f7 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)(+0x57 Native)
7c:M 00000000002bdfe0 000007feee7ce621 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()(+0x20 IL,+0x71 Native)
7d:M 00000000002be060 000007feee7c9063 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()(+0xf0 IL,+0x2e3 Native)
7e:M 00000000002be130 000007feee7c93c3 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)(+0x45 IL,+0xb3 Native)
7f:M 00000000002be1f0 000007feee7cb45a MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)(+0x39 IL,+0x14a Native)
80:M 00000000002be2a0 000007feee7cb2e0 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)(+0x5b IL,+0x80 Native)
81:M 00000000002be2f0 000007feee7cb15a System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)(+0x7e IL,+0x5a Native)
82:M 00000000002be350 000007feee7cb0e7 MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)(+0x11 IL,+0x47 Native)
83:M 00000000002be3b0 000007feee7c846c System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)(+0xce IL,+0x2bc Native)
84:M 00000000002be450 000007feee7ca9d0 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)(+0x129 IL,+0x140 Native)
85:M 00000000002be550 000007feee9759d7 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int32, Int64, Int64)
86:U 00000000002be5e0 000007feec1fb42e clr!UMThunkStub+0x6e
87:U 00000000002be670 0000000076c29bd1 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1ad
88:U 00000000002be730 0000000076c298da user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x3b5
89:M 00000000002be7b0 000007feee7f5900 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
8a:M 00000000002be880 000007feee7c7332 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)(+0x48 IL,+0x112 Native)
8b:M 00000000002be920 000007fee361f2ea System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)(+0xf0 IL,+0x17a Native)
8c:M 00000000002be9c0 000007fee361ebf7 System.Windows.Application.Run()(+0x67 Native)
8d:M 00000000002bea00 000007fe8cc80100 *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for exe
XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedApplication.Main()(+0x0 IL,+0x70 Native)
8e:U 00000000002bea40 000007feec19a7f3 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
8f:U 00000000002bea80 000007feec19a6de clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
90:U 00000000002beac0 000007feec19ae76 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x251
91:U 00000000002bec70 000007feec327749 clr!RunMain+0x1e7
92:U 00000000002bee50 000007feec327a8e clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xb6
93:U 00000000002bf140 000007feec327987 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x506
94:U 00000000002bf750 000007feec32790a clr!ExecuteEXE+0x3f
95:U 00000000002bf7c0 000007feec327862 clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xae
96:U 00000000002bf850 000007feec324174 clr!CorExeMain+0x14
97:U 00000000002bf890 000007fef78a72fd mscoreei!CorExeMain+0xe0
98:U 00000000002bf8e0 000007fef7a25b21 mscoree!CorExeMain_Exported+0x57
99:U 00000000002bf910 0000000076da59dd kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
9a:U 00000000002bf940 0000000076eda631 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

The stack pattern here shows it's an re-entrance:

```
4f:U 00000000002bc1d0 0000000076c29bd1 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1ad
50:U 00000000002bc290 0000000076c272cb user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xc3
51:U 00000000002bc2f0 0000000076c26829 user32!_fnDWORD+0x2d
52:U 00000000002bc350 0000000076efbd75 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue
53:U 00000000002bc3d8 0000000076c2908a user32!NtUserPeekMessage+0xa
54:U 00000000002bc3e0 0000000076c29055 user32!PeekMessageW+0x105
55:U 00000000002bc430 000007fefebaff92 ole32!CCliModalLoop::MyPeekMessage+0x52 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 1733]
56:U 00000000002bc4a0 000007fefebb0109 ole32!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage+0x49 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 1500]
57:U 00000000002bc510 000007fefeb3e153 ole32!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x5353f
58:U 00000000002bc560 000007fefec0a422 ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0x102 [d:\w7rtm\com\ole32\com\dcomrem\sync.cxx @ 109]
```

The `PropertyChangedEventManager` uses `ReaderWriterLock` when binding changed, so we have to `DisableProcessing` when changing properties in the view model to avoid the issue.